# Retrieving new mongoid criteria based on filter in parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I have a schema where product has_many articles
I am retrieving a mongoid criteria based on scopes I created on the article model :

```
criteria = Article.published.with_image
```

From this criteria, I would like now to find all articles for which their products have a certain subject_id (or a subset of subject_ids).
I tried to writte :

```
criteria = criteria.in('product.subject_ids': data[:subjects])
```

where data[:subjects] is an array of subject_ids but this doesn't work.

Is there a clean way to do this with mongoid without having to loop over all articles from the first criteria or pluck all product_ids from the first criteria ?

Answer (score 1):

How about any of these?

```
Project.where(:subject_id.in => data[:subject_id], :article_ids.in =>  criteria.pluck(:id))

criteria = Article.eagerload(:products).published.with_image
criterial.map {|art| return art.product if data[:subjects].any? {|subjects| art.product.subject_ids.include?(id)  }
```